Why do I get LNK2019 error for ImGui with GLFW/Vulkan?

I am trying to create a menu for my Vulkan app using GLFW and ImGui. The problem is that I am getting "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol" all over the place and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

For now I am only trying to run the code from here: https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/examples/example_glfw_vulkan/main.cpp

And what I get when running it is:
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct ImGuiContext * __cdecl ImGui::CreateContext(struct ImFontAtlas *)" (?CreateContext@ImGui@@YAPEAUImGuiContext@@PEAUImFontAtlas@@@Z) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui::DestroyContext(struct ImGuiContext *)" (?DestroyContext@ImGui@@YAXPEAUImGuiContext@@@Z) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct ImGuiIO & __cdecl ImGui::GetIO(void)" (?GetIO@ImGui@@YAAEAUImGuiIO@@XZ) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui::NewFrame(void)" (?NewFrame@ImGui@@YAXXZ) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui::Render(void)" (?Render@ImGui@@YAXXZ) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct ImDrawData * __cdecl ImGui::GetDrawData(void)" (?GetDrawData@ImGui@@YAPEAUImDrawData@@XZ) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui::ShowDemoWindow(bool *)" (?ShowDemoWindow@ImGui@@YAXPEA_N@Z) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui::StyleColorsDark(struct ImGuiStyle *)" (?StyleColorsDark@ImGui@@YAXPEAUImGuiStyle@@@Z) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl ImGui::Begin(char const *,bool *,int)" (?Begin@ImGui@@YA_NPEBDPEA_NH@Z) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui::End(void)" (?End@ImGui@@YAXXZ) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui::SameLine(float,float)" (?SameLine@ImGui@@YAXMM@Z) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui::Text(char const *,...)" (?Text@ImGui@@YAXPEBDZZ) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl ImGui::Button(char const *,struct ImVec2 const &)" (?Button@ImGui@@YA_NPEBDAEBUImVec2@@@Z) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl ImGui::Checkbox(char const *,bool *)" (?Checkbox@ImGui@@YA_NPEBDPEA_N@Z) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl ImGui::SliderFloat(char const *,float *,float,float,char const *,int)" (?SliderFloat@ImGui@@YA_NPEBDPEAMMM0H@Z) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl ImGui::ColorEdit3(char const *,float * const,int)" (?ColorEdit3@ImGui@@YA_NPEBDQEAMH@Z) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl ImGui::DebugCheckVersionAndDataLayout(char const *,unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64)" (?DebugCheckVersionAndDataLayout@ImGui@@YA_NPEBD_K11111@Z) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl ImGui::MemAlloc(unsigned __int64)" (?MemAlloc@ImGui@@YAPEAX_K@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl ImVector<struct VkPhysicalDevice_T *>::reserve(int)" (?reserve@?$ImVector@PEAUVkPhysicalDevice_T@@@@QEAAXH@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui::MemFree(void *)" (?MemFree@ImGui@@YAXPEAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl ImVector<struct VkPhysicalDevice_T *>::~ImVector<struct VkPhysicalDevice_T *>(void)" (??1?$ImVector@PEAUVkPhysicalDevice_T@@@@QEAA@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForVulkan(struct GLFWwindow *,bool)" (?ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForVulkan@@YA_NPEAUGLFWwindow@@_N@Z) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui_ImplGlfw_Shutdown(void)" (?ImGui_ImplGlfw_Shutdown@@YAXXZ) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame(void)" (?ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame@@YAXXZ) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui_ImplGlfw_Sleep(int)" (?ImGui_ImplGlfw_Sleep@@YAXH@Z) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl ImGui_ImplVulkan_Init(struct ImGui_ImplVulkan_InitInfo *)" (?ImGui_ImplVulkan_Init@@YA_NPEAUImGui_ImplVulkan_InitInfo@@@Z) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui_ImplVulkan_Shutdown(void)" (?ImGui_ImplVulkan_Shutdown@@YAXXZ) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui_ImplVulkan_NewFrame(void)" (?ImGui_ImplVulkan_NewFrame@@YAXXZ) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui_ImplVulkan_RenderDrawData(struct ImDrawData *,struct VkCommandBuffer_T *,struct VkPipeline_T *)" (?ImGui_ImplVulkan_RenderDrawData@@YAXPEAUImDrawData@@PEAUVkCommandBuffer_T@@PEAUVkPipeline_T@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl FrameRender(struct ImGui_ImplVulkanH_Window *,struct ImDrawData *)" (?FrameRender@@YAXPEAUImGui_ImplVulkanH_Window@@PEAUImDrawData@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui_ImplVulkan_SetMinImageCount(unsigned int)" (?ImGui_ImplVulkan_SetMinImageCount@@YAXI@Z) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui_ImplVulkanH_CreateOrResizeWindow(struct VkInstance_T *,struct VkPhysicalDevice_T *,struct VkDevice_T *,struct ImGui_ImplVulkanH_Window *,unsigned int,struct VkAllocationCallbacks const *,int,int,unsigned int)" (?ImGui_ImplVulkanH_CreateOrResizeWindow@@YAXPEAUVkInstance_T@@PEAUVkPhysicalDevice_T@@PEAUVkDevice_T@@PEAUImGui_ImplVulkanH_Window@@IPEBUVkAllocationCallbacks@@HHI@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl SetupVulkanWindow(struct ImGui_ImplVulkanH_Window *,struct VkSurfaceKHR_T *,int,int)" (?SetupVulkanWindow@@YAXPEAUImGui_ImplVulkanH_Window@@PEAUVkSurfaceKHR_T@@HH@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ImGui_ImplVulkanH_DestroyWindow(struct VkInstance_T *,struct VkDevice_T *,struct ImGui_ImplVulkanH_Window *,struct VkAllocationCallbacks const *)" (?ImGui_ImplVulkanH_DestroyWindow@@YAXPEAUVkInstance_T@@PEAUVkDevice_T@@PEAUImGui_ImplVulkanH_Window@@PEBUVkAllocationCallbacks@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl CleanupVulkanWindow(void)" (?CleanupVulkanWindow@@YAXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct VkSurfaceFormatKHR __cdecl ImGui_ImplVulkanH_SelectSurfaceFormat(struct VkPhysicalDevice_T *,struct VkSurfaceKHR_T *,enum VkFormat const *,int,enum VkColorSpaceKHR)" (?ImGui_ImplVulkanH_SelectSurfaceFormat@@YA?AUVkSurfaceFormatKHR@@PEAUVkPhysicalDevice_T@@PEAUVkSurfaceKHR_T@@PEBW4VkFormat@@HW4VkColorSpaceKHR@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl SetupVulkanWindow(struct ImGui_ImplVulkanH_Window *,struct VkSurfaceKHR_T *,int,int)" (?SetupVulkanWindow@@YAXPEAUImGui_ImplVulkanH_Window@@PEAUVkSurfaceKHR_T@@HH@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "enum VkPresentModeKHR __cdecl ImGui_ImplVulkanH_SelectPresentMode(struct VkPhysicalDevice_T *,struct VkSurfaceKHR_T *,enum VkPresentModeKHR const *,int)" (?ImGui_ImplVulkanH_SelectPresentMode@@YA?AW4VkPresentModeKHR@@PEAUVkPhysicalDevice_T@@PEAUVkSurfaceKHR_T@@PEBW41@H@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl SetupVulkanWindow(struct ImGui_ImplVulkanH_Window *,struct VkSurfaceKHR_T *,int,int)" (?SetupVulkanWindow@@YAXPEAUImGui_ImplVulkanH_Window@@PEAUVkSurfaceKHR_T@@HH@Z)

This is my dependency folder structure:


I will add the picture with my settings, maybe it helps..




Do you compile and link the imgui files?

@Raildex I only copied those .h and .cpp files in a new ImGui folder. As you can see, it is inside the include folder which is used to be compiled.

putting them in a folder does not mean they are part of the compilation process

Well, they are not in my actual source code, since the demo doesn't include those files. Do you suggest to also add them in my source folder?

Do not post images, and whenever you want to use someone elses code (e.g. a library) you should use a package manager. Since you use visual studio you should learn about how to use vcpkg and use that to build with vulkan (https://vcpkg.link/ports/vulkan-sdk-components)

@GenesysRTA ImGUI files are best left in their own folder (IMHO) but you do need to compile and link them. The red circles indicate that is not currently happening. Somehow you have excluded them from your project. I forget the exact thing you need to do but it starts with a right click on the icon and then selecting 'properties' or some such.

@PepijnKramer I used vcpkg and needed to added the imgui_impl_glfw and imgui_impl_vulkan .h and .cpp files manually to my project. It works but only God knows how.

@john fixed it by doing whats in the comment above.

@GenesysRTA In VS files only get compiled if they are added to the project. If you copy a file into the project directory you still need to pick 'Add Existing File ...'. That's just how VS works.
